# Problems adding credit card for app verification

Tags: facebook, credit-card

I'm trying to create a test app, which requires giving Facebook a credit card for verification (or a cellphone, which I don't have). Unfortunately, when I enter my credit card information (and it's all correct and valid), I get the error:

> Sorry, we were unable to process your order at this time.

How can I add a credit card and verify an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be *two* different methods for adding a credit card - The *obvious* one is directly through the standard Accounts page.

- https://secure.facebook.com/settings?tab=payments&section=methods
  [image: facebook account setting]

The second, is through another page, but I haven't found where the page comes from. This (hard-to-find) second page worked fine for me. I added my credit card, and was able to create a test app with no further problems.

- https://secure.facebook.com/cards.php
  [image: facebook account setting two]

Update - I finally received a response from the Facebook support team, and they suggested that I use the *second* link, to fix the problem. While I'm sure the comments are correct, that this is an orphan link - it's still a bit funny.

Comment: The second is an orphan link pre the new UI layout.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @phwd. Still, it's odd that one link works and the other doesn't - I guess they changed more than just the *UI*, and added new cc-checking code.